# "Upgrade to 12.04" greyed out as option on 12.04 Disc

Tags: upgrade

I have 10.04.4 LTS installed and have inserted a new 12.04 official disc to use for the upgrade, although when I get to the upgrade page on the disc, the option to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 is greyed out. Is there anything I need to do first to allow this radio button to activate?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Also, this computer is not connected to the internet right now so this is why Im using a disc.

Answer (score 0):

You really would do well to boot into the 'Try Ubuntu' option before attempting either to install or upgrade.  Also please note that however you choose to upgrade, the process is not always data safe, so please back up.  When you eventually choose the 'install' option after trying 12.04 and backing up everything, there may be an option to retain your data.

Comment: whether i directly choose the "install" or "try ubuntu" then install, i still get the greyed out option of "upgrade ubuntu" from 10.04 to 12.04, meaning i cannot select it for upgrading purposes. im not sure why i dont have the option available to upgrade. any ideas?

Comment: I have been able to emulate what you are doing as I my wife's computer has 10.04 installed.  I does offer me the option to upgrade.  I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the installer is detecting a flaw in your 10.04 which would later give problems.  If it is in fact suggesting that a clean install would solve many hours of pain later, who am I to argue?

Comment: there are a couple things i will check when i have a moment... #1 to check if i need to do all updates first, #2 to check if i need to allow uprades first before trying to upgrade (regardless of if i do it by disc or internet). i'll post anything i find out.

Comment: not really related, but i want to thank you barry for all youve done to help ubuntu

Comment: The one difference between my wife's installation and yours is that hers is connected by wire to the internet.  Haven't checked this out, but will if it becomes an issue for others.